# Cell from ExcelRange

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

This problem has me completely puzzled.

I have a Excel document which loads in just fine.
It has rows, columns and data and I want to iterate through the rows.
But EPPLus is odd.

I take the second row:

```
ExcelRange range1 = worksheet.Cells[2, worksheet.Dimension.Start.Column, 2, worksheet.Dimension.End.Column];
```

Which gives me `{A2:D2}` Splendid! so far so good but then I want the first cell of the row:

```
ExcelRange range2 = range1[1,1];
```

Which give me `{A1}` and to make matter worse, the value of `range1` has also changed to `{A1}` instead of the row I selected.

How can I resolve this issue and take a ExcelRange from an ExcelRange?

This has me completely puzzled .... thanks for anyhelp

Comment: Why are you trying to get ranges from other ranges in the first place?

Comment: The  document contains a data structure with rows of data. Each row had to be validated. There for I take the row and forward it to a method to validate the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code behind the `ExcelRange` Indexer you will see that the `get` will actually set the base address (the nested `else`):

```
public ExcelRange this[string Address]
{
    get
    {
        if (_worksheet.Names.ContainsKey(Address))
        {
            if (_worksheet.Names[Address].IsName)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                base.Address = _worksheet.Names[Address].Address;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            base.Address = Address;
        }
        _rtc = null;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Why they did it this way I am not sure (I assume there its an implementation detail).  But that would explain why referencing another address changes the selected range. So, like Benexx said, have to do a direct reference from the `Cells` collection of the `Worksheet`.

Answer (score 4):

I did have the same problem, to get the correct start cell:

```
var range2 = worksheet.Cells[range1.Start.Row, range1.Start.Column];
```

And the same for the bottom right cell:

```
var range3 = worksheet.Cells[range1.End.Row, range1.End.Column];
```

Comment: But I for example want to take the first cell from range2

Comment: I guess you can also use var range2 = range1[range1.Start.Row, range1.Start.Column];

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Offset method to get a sub-range of an ExcelRange.  This give you a new instance of ExcelRange and does not modify the original instance.

https://www.epplussoftware.com/docs/5.5/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.html#OfficeOpenXml_ExcelRangeBase_Offset_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Here is an example:

```
public static void AlternateRowColor(ExcelRange range)
{
    for (var rowOffset = 1; rowOffset < range.Rows; rowOffset += 2)
    {
        using (var rowRange = range.Offset(rowOffset, 0, 1, range.Columns))
        {
            rowRange.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            rowRange.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Cornsilk);
        }
    }
}
```